# Python: How to improve performance of a script to obtain the Bounding Box of a set of points

Tags: python, performance, memory-management, coding-style

I have a set of points (x and y) and i wish to know the maximum and Minimum values of X and Y (the Bounding Box). I coded these lines where i read all points with list comprehension and after i use max and min on X and Y. In the end i delete the points.

This solution is not memory efficency because i need to read all points

```
points = [(p.x,p.y) for p in lasfile.File(inFile,None,'r')] # read in list comprehension
X_Max = max(zip(*points)[0])
X_Min = min(zip(*points)[0])
Y_Max = max(zip(*points)[1])
Y_Min = min(zip(*points)[1])
del points
```

I am asking a suggetion to avoid this step (store all points in the memory).
Thanks in advance
Gianni

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
X_Max = float('-inf')
X_Min = float('+inf')
Y_Max = float('-inf')
Y_Min = float('+inf')

for p in lasfile.File(inFile,None,'r'):
    X_Max = max(X_Max, p.x)
    X_Min = min(X_Min, p.x)
    Y_Max = max(Y_Max, p.y)
    Y_Min = min(Y_Min, p.y)
```

This way you only loop once over your file, as well as avoiding having more than one point in memory at a time.

**EDIT** `File()` is providing a iterator, which is only reading one line at a time from the file and supplying it to the loop variable `p`, as and when required.

In your question you used square brackets around your initial points assignment.  This is a list comprehension which, as the name suggests, creates a list - so all points are held in memory from that point on.  If you used parentheses instead like this:

```
points = ((p.x,p.y) for p in lasfile.File(inFile,None,'r'))

X_Max = float('-inf')
X_Min = float('+inf')
Y_Max = float('-inf')
Y_Min = float('+inf')

for p in points:
    X_Max = max(X_Max, p.x)
    X_Min = min(X_Min, p.x)
    Y_Max = max(Y_Max, p.y)
    Y_Min = min(Y_Min, p.y)
```

...then Python doesn't create a list, but a generator/iterator - which would return one point at a time until the file is exhausted.  This would avoid having all points in memory at the same time - but can only be iterated over once.

For the sake of simplicity though, I've dropped the creation of an additional iterator in favour of just using the `lasfile.File()` one directly.

Comment: Points are still being stored in memory here.

Comment: Thanks Steve, but my idea is try to not store points (more than 2 million) in the memory

Comment: It's a generator, so it should only have one point at a time in memory.  Note the parentheses rather than square brackets around the first line.

Comment: Why the `points` generator and not just `for p in lasfile.File(inFile,None,'r'): X_Max = max(X_Max, p.x) ...`?

Comment: @Mr.Steak Good point. Tidiness, perhaps?  Tenuous, I know.  I'll drop it.

Comment: You should note that it is the `File` class that's providing the generator (assuming the OP uses libLAS, which I think he does).

Comment: @Mr.Steak I've added some more explanation text

Comment: @SteveMayne: thanks for your help. With these large data set (> 2 million of points) i have always problem in Python. recently I wrote these posts in stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12923935/python-improve-memory-efficiency-of-a-script 
and this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883237/python-improve-the-efficency-of-my-script-using-multiprocessing-module-tips-an
to explain these problems

Comment: @SteveMayne i will test tonight for sure, and you will get feedback on SO. Today is/was a meeting (full) day and now I am on PC to preparing the data of tonight. Anyway,  please could i ask to write your solution using points = ((p.x,p.y) for p in lasfile.File(inFile,None,'r'))? Thanks in advance Gianni

Comment: @SteveMayne: with your solution i have X_Max as 313372.98 (what i need). Some people suggest to use list comprehension instead of for when you have more a 1 million of point (sppeding performance). I will try to find a solution you your code and points = ((p.x,p.y) for p in lasfile.File(inFile,None,'r'))

Comment: @Gianni I've filled in the gaps in the generator version of my answer.  The list comprehension won't save you anything over using a generator in the example above - and it will cost you masses of RAM.  To clarify - The list comprehension is the bit in square brackets on the first line of your code - not the max() calls, passing in the full list.

Comment: @SteveMayne thanks again Steve, you are really clear and expert

Comment: No problem @Gianni - please don't forget to 'accept' this answer if it's the one that fixed it for you :-)

Comment: @SteveMayne: done :). If you have time could you give a look a this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12923935/python-improve-memory-efficiency-of-a-script. I think a answer can be really quoted by the comunity that use Shapefile module http://code.google.com/p/pyshp/

Answer (score 3):

You could use a generator expression for `points` and use the `key` argument for [`max`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#max) and [`min`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#min):

```
from itertools import tee
points = ((p.x,p.y) for p in lasfile.File(inFile,None,'r'))
points = tee(points, 4)

X_Max = max(points[0], key=lambda x:x[0])[0]
X_Min = min(points[1], key=lambda x:x[0])[0]
Y_Max = max(points[2], key=lambda x:x[1])[1]
Y_Min = min(points[3], key=lambda x:x[1])[1]
```

**Update:**

I added a call to [itertools.tee](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) to duplicate the original generator.

As noted in the comments, this solution has the downside that you have to (unnecessaryly) iterate over your file 4 times. Calculating the maxes and mins on every iteration, as [@SteveMayne](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12953279/637284) does, saves you from this.

Comment: Thanks halex, but my idea is try to not store points (more than 2 million) in the memory. PS: i didn't downvote (I never do)

Comment: The points should not be stored in memory because of the generator expression made with `(...)` instead of `[...]`. The points are fetched one at a time.

Comment: Are you sure this will work? After the first `max` call, the generator `points` will be exhausted, so the following call to `min` will result in an exception.

Comment: @Mr.Steak that's what I was thinking too.  Even if it worked, you'd have to iterate over the file 4 times to do something you could do with a single loop.

Comment: @halex: with your solution i have X_Max as "(313372.98, 6956949.2700000005)" instead of one value (the X max)

Comment: @Gianni Sorry. I now fixed it. The problem was that `max` and `min` returned the whole point of x and y value as a tuple of 2 elements. So I added another access for the first element for the x values and the second for y values. Thanks for being so attentive :).

Comment: @halex: it;s a pleasure test and see if there are some bugs. Great job you and Steve Mayne

Comment: @halex both solution work without memory problem. Maybe your solution is a little more fast. It's strange, Python is slow in X_Max = max(points[0], key=lambda x:x[0])[0], and the rest is quite fast